# Prevent closing Bootstrap modal with Promise

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Bootsrap based framework.

Generally speaking, when a form content is updated, I can provide an asynchronous feature which display another modal to confirm that updates can be lost before closing the form; this feature returns a status indicating if the user confirmed or not...

So my question is: how can I prevent a Bootstrap modal from closing when this modal contains a form for which the user don't want to lose updates, when the confirmation dialog is asynchronous?

Best regards,

Thierry

Answer (score -1):

I finally handled my use case.

I added a "shown.bs.modal" event handler to disable standard Bootstrap click handlers and add my custom modal manager...

Best regards,

Thierry